# I want to build something like that if a user enters in a room he recieve a notification in swift ios is it possible?

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation, core-location

i have tried with measuring distance between destination latitude and longitude and current lat long it is woking fine in long range but in close range like within 10 meters it is not working accurately i just want to show a message on screen if user's distance form destination lat long is less than 1 meter

```
class LocationManager: NSObject,  ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    let manager = CLLocationManager()
    @Published var coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    @Published var alt: CLLocationDistance?
    var center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)
    @Published var distance: Double = 0
    
    @Published var entered: Bool = false
    @Published var exit: Bool = false
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        manager.delegate = self
    }
    
    func createCircularRegion() {
        center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 23.178193, longitude: 75.786546)
        let radius: CLLocationDistance = 1
        let circularRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: center, radius: radius, identifier: UUID().uuidString)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(center.latitude, forKey: "centerLatitude")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(center.longitude, forKey: "centerLongitude")
        entered = circularRegion.notifyOnEntry
        exit = circularRegion.notifyOnExit
        print(circularRegion)
    }
    
    func calculateDistance(crrLat: Double, crrLong: Double) {
        let destinationLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 23.179100, longitude: 75.788653)
        let currentLocation = CLLocation(latitude: crrLat, longitude: crrLong)
        distance = currentLocation.distance(from: destinationLocation)
        print(String(format: "The distance to my buddy is %.02f m", distance))
    }
    
    func calculateDistanceWithHarvensin(crrLat: Double, crrLong: Double, desLat: Double = 23.1780068, desLong: Double = 75.7865060, radius: Double = 6367444.7) -> Double {
        print("CrrLat \(crrLat) = CrrLong = \(crrLong)")
        let haversin = { (angle: Double) -> Double in
            return (1 - cos(angle))/2
        }
        
        let ahaversin = { (angle: Double) -> Double in
            return 2 * asin(sqrt(angle))
        }
        
        // degree to radian
        let dToR = { (angle: Double) -> Double in
            return (angle / 360) * 2 * .pi
        }
        
        let lat1 = dToR(crrLat)
        let lon1 = dToR(crrLong)
        let lat2 = dToR(desLat)
        let lon2 = dToR(desLong)
        
        return radius * ahaversin(haversin(lat2 - lat1) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * haversin(lon2 - lon1))

    }
    
    func getLocation() {
        
//        let status = locationManager.authorizationStatus
//        switch status {
//        case .notDetermined:
//            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
//
//        case .authorizedAlways:
//            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
//
//        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
//            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
//
//        case .authorized:
//            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
//
//        default :
//            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
//        }
        
        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    func locationManager(
        _ manager: CLLocationManager,
        didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus
    ) {
        // Handle changes if location permissions
    }
    

    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.last {
            let latitude = location.coordinate.latitude
            let longitude = location.coordinate.longitude
            let altitude = location.altitude
//            print("Lat = \(latitude) & Long = \(longitude) & Alt = \(altitude)")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(latitude, forKey: "lat")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(longitude, forKey: "long")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(altitude, forKey: "alt")
            coordinates = location.coordinate
            alt = altitude
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("ERROR = \(error)")
    }
    
    func monitoRegionAtLocation(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D, identifier: String) {
        
        if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLCircularRegion.self) {
            let maxDistance = manager.maximumRegionMonitoringDistance
            let region = CLCircularRegion(center: center, radius: maxDistance, identifier: identifier)

            region.notifyOnEntry = true
            region.notifyOnExit = true
            
            manager.startMonitoring(for: region)
        }
        
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
        if let region = region as? CLCircularRegion {
            let identifier = region.identifier
            print("Entered in region")
            entered = true
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
        print("Exited Region")
        exit = true
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You’re looking for something called “presence detection”, this usually uses a number of techniques, as gps generally isn’t a viable option in doors. One technique is to use “beacons” and a form of signal triangulation to determine which beacon the phone is closed to - do some research - you’ll find it’s generally hit and miss

Comment: GPS is the wrong tool for this