# can I calculate accurate distance between two latitude and longitude inside a house within 5 meters?

Tags: swift, geolocation, gps, latitude-longitude

I want to calculate distance between two coordinates within 5 meters or even within one meters is it possible

I have tried haversine formula but not getting the desired result

```
func calculateDistanceWithHaversin(crrLat: Double, crrLong: Double, desLat: Double = 23.1780068, desLong: Double = 75.7865060, radius: Double = 6367444.7) -> Double {
        print("CrrLat \(crrLat) = CrrLong = \(crrLong)")
        let haversin = { (angle: Double) -> Double in
            return (1 - cos(angle))/2
        }

        let ahaversin = { (angle: Double) -> Double in
            return 2 * asin(sqrt(angle))
        }

        // degree to radian
        let dToR = { (angle: Double) -> Double in
            return (angle / 360) * 2 * .pi
        }

        let lat1 = dToR(crrLat)
        let lon1 = dToR(crrLong)
        let lat2 = dToR(desLat)
        let lon2 = dToR(desLong)

        return radius * ahaversin(haversin(lat2 - lat1) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * haversin(lon2 - lon1))

    }
```

i have tried this also

```
    func calculateDistance(crrLat: Double, crrLong: Double) {
        let destinationLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 23.1780068, longitude: 75.7865060)
        let currentLocation = CLLocation(latitude: crrLat, longitude: crrLong)
        distance = currentLocation.distance(from: destinationLocation)
        print(String(format: "The distance to my buddy is %.02f m", distance))
    }
```

Comment: You are unlikely to get the desired results inside a building. Even outside with a clear sky with lots of satellites in view you won't get 1 meter resolution.

Comment: Could you get us an example of the input you tried and the output of your program, and the expected output?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi i have passed lat long of center of my room as destination and passing device's current lat long as input but even if i put my device in the middle of my room it is showing that distance is more than 5 meter i am expecting that the result should came as zero or less than one meter

Comment: We need the data and your results. For privacy reason, just go to google maps, and select a buildings (possibly in a different country as your). Take lat/long of two part of the same building and try with your methods, and put such additional data here, so we can test better. I assume it is just a unit error.

Comment: You already asked this question. This type of precision is not possible with gps indoors https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74555762/i-want-to-build-something-like-that-if-a-user-enters-in-a-room-he-recieve-a-noti

Comment: Your problem is likely not your method of calculating distance, but rather the accuracy of your position values. The GPS accuracy on an iOS device is not great even outdoors with a clear view of the sky. (I’ve seen from 5-15 meters of “slop” in outdoor readings). Indoors, all bets are off. You might get a km or more of slop in your readings. The structure of the building interferes with the GPS position calculation.

Comment: just to follow up on what @DuncanC said, you should plot the coordinates you get in something like google earth to see how accurate they are inside the building.  you should get reasonable results when you're close to windows / open doors, but as soon as you move to the center you're probably out of luck.  I've seen people triangulating via wifi or bluetooth, but setting up beacons needs to be done correctly

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate distance with this Builtin Function provided by CoreLocation . The provided distance will be in meters

```
import CoreLocation

let locationOne = CLLocation(latitude: 37.899, longitude: 74.8989)
let locationTwo = CLLocation(latitude: 38.0900, longitude: 78.98898)
let distance = locationOne.distance(from: locationTwo)
```

Comment: thanku umer for your responce. I have tried this function but not able to get the actual distance even if i placed the device on destination coordinates it is showing distance more than 5 meters

Comment: You might also want to look into the `desired accuracy` setting: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423836-desiredaccuracy